# How to recover text that was encoded with base64?

Tags: python, base64, restore, corruption

How can I recover a text that was corrupted by base64 encoding? E.g.

```
f('Dan=E7a')=Dança
```

I tried with python but couldn't get it right.

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupted by"? Is that text base64 encoded?

Comment: There was a bug the was "breaking data encoding" http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749 I could fix the bug but one record in the datastore is bad and I want to recover it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like [Quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, not base-64.

There's a module in the Python standard library called [`quopri`](http://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html) that should be able to convert the text.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I still couldn't get it right since when I run `decodestring` I get chars like `Dan\xe7a` The bug was "breaking data encoding" http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749

Comment: @Niklas: What does `len("Dan\xe7a")`return? If it's 5, you have the CORRECT answer. `\xe7` is an escape sequence that represents the byte whose ordinal is 0xe7. Look at the entry for E7 in this table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252. If the len is NOT 5, show us your code.

Comment: `>>> len("Dan\xe7a")`
5 so I'm going to run to program with a file with the encoded text. Thanks for the help

Comment: How did you convert "Dan\xe7a" to ascii or unicode? after apply decodestring to the string.

Comment: I reply me if it is useful for someone. unicode(decodestring(content), 'iso-8859-1')  Because the content-type is iso-8859-1.

Comment: I just found on online converter and pasted i/o http://www.motobit.com/util/quoted-printable-decoder.asp