# Textarea add rare symbols

Tags: django, google-app-engine, post, textarea, symbols

I have problems with my textarea. When someone copy text from an html or .txt and paste it in my textarea, the post have rare symbols like: =20, =space, =3D...
Anyone have some idea about my problem?? And how could I fix it?
My textarea is:

```
<textarea id="id_message" cols="40" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
```

I use Markdown, but I have tried this without javascript and the problem is the same.

I use Django in Google app engine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html

Comment: Maybe my problem was similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440092/how-to-recover-text-that-was-encoded-with-base64

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code - the rest of the form, and the handler code.

Comment: Thank you very much. The method decodestring from quopri fixed my problem. ^^